# XSL: Build a unique map from child nodes in multiple xml files, then display it in a table

Tags: xml, xslt

Use XSL to build a unique map from child nodes, then display it in a table

I would like to create a xsl that takes the following xml documents as input

Source.xml

```
<root>
<children>
<child>
Source-A
</child>
<child>
Source-B
</child>
</children>
</root>
```

Source-A.xml

```
<child>
 <Objects>
  <Object>
   <Key>Key-1234</Key>
  </Object>
  <Object>
   <Key>Key-5678</Key>
  </Object>
 </Objects>
</child>
```

Source-B.xml

```
<child>
 <Objects>
  <Object>
   <Key>Key-5678</Key>
  </Object>
  <Object>
   <Key>Key-ABCD</Key>
  </Object>
 </Objects>
</child>
```

and creates some html output that looks like this.

```
<table border=1>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Key
  </td>
  <td>
   Key-1234
  </td>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   Source-A
  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>
   Key
  </td>
  <td>
   Key-5678
  </td>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   Source-A
   Source-B
  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>
   Key
  </td>
  <td>
   Key-ABCD
  </td>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   Source-B
  </td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure it's even possible, any hints on how to do it? Or am I trying to do something thats not possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <!--<xsl:variable name="keyMap" />-->
      <xsl:variable name="keyMap">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/children/child">
          <xsl:variable name="object" select="."/>
          <!--<xsl:value-of select="$object"/>-->
          <xsl:for-each select="document(concat(translate($object,'&#10;',''),'.xml'))/child/Objects/Object">
             <xsl:value-of select="Key"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$keyMap"/>

    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Two phase transformation with `node-set()` extension function.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:key name="kKeyByValue" match="Key" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vFirstPass">
            <xsl:for-each select="root/children/child">
                <xsl:variable name="vSource" select="normalize-space()"/>
                <source href="{$vSource}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat($vSource,'.xml'))
                                            /child/Objects/Object/Key"/>
                </source>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($vFirstPass)/*"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="Key[count(.|key('kKeyByValue',.)[1]) = 1]">
        <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('kKeyByValue',.)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../@href)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Key-1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Source-A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Key-5678</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Source-A Source-B</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Key-ABCD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Source-B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Without extensions, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kChildByDocument"
             match="child"
             use="generate-id(
                     document(concat(normalize-space(),'.xml'),.)
                  )"/>
    <xsl:key name="kRootByKeys"
             match="/"
             use="child/Objects/Object/Key"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSource" select="/"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="getDocuments">
        <xsl:param name="pDocuments" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="pURIs" select="root/children/child"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pURIs">
                <xsl:call-template name="getDocuments">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pDocuments"
                     select="$pDocuments |
                             document(concat(normalize-space($pURIs[1]),
                                             '.xml'),
                                      .)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pURIs"
                                    select="$pURIs[position()>1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:call-template name="makeRows">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pDocuments"
                                        select="$pDocuments"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </table>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="makeRows">
        <xsl:param name="pDocuments" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="pKeys"
                   select="$pDocuments/child/Objects/Object/Key"/>
        <xsl:if test="$pKeys">
            <xsl:variable name="vKey" select="$pKeys[1]"/>
            <tr>
                <td>Key</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$vKey"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$pDocuments[
                                             key('kRootByKeys',$vKey)
                                          ]">
                        <xsl:variable name="vDocument"
                                      select="generate-id()"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$vSource">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                 select="normalize-space(
                                            key('kChildByDocument',
                                                $vDocument)
                                         )"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                            <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:call-template name="makeRows">
                <xsl:with-param name="pDocuments" select="$pDocuments"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pKeys" select="$pKeys[.!=$vKey]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow - that's quite a transform! +1 from me!

Comment: @Jon Egerton: Yes. First recursive template wouldn't be needed if the input source has full URIs instead of calculated ones. Also, Directly grouping isn't posible because `key()` function works per document. Other aproach would be to merge those multiple sources  applying a two phase transformation, this time grouping uniques keys.